An American Heist Movie from the 2000s
I'm looking for a heist movie that i've only watched a small part. 
A couple of people were planned to rob a safe next to the nightclub. 
Their plan was drill the wall between the safe and the nightclub at the most crowded hours to absorb the noise and reach the safe. One of them was working at the nightclub and was trying to encourage people to make more and more noise.
For this he went to outside and allowed under aged teens to get inside for make the nightclub even more crowded and noisy. He was buying drinks to people for make them drunk and make sure they're happy and noisy.
I can't remember much his physical appereance but he's white, around 35 years of age and medium sized. 
The robbers were about 5 people. They succeesed in drilling the wall and reach the safe but I couldn't watch the rest of it. 

Stark Raving Mad?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19ae_wJwD7Y

This is Stark Raving Mad (2002) with Seann William Scott

Ben McGewan has a deal with Chinatown's non-Chinese gang boss, Gregory, to steal one of four mythical god statues reputed to give immense power. This theft, in exchange for wiping out his debt and a fortune to pay his team of frustrated experts. They organize a wild after hours party in a nightclub as cover to break into the vault of the bank next door. Alas, from the start things go wrong ever worse, for everyone.



Yes , this is the movie .. Thank you guys for your quick reply !

You are welcome, feel free to upvote if this helped and, when permitted, mark as correct.
